# Does XQuartz work on macOS Mojave?

Tags: macos, xquartz

The latest version is from 2016:

https://www.xquartz.org/

[image]

I will try it out .. but wonder if there were some pointers / warnings about this..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, the latest version of XQuartz works just fine on my macOS Mojave machine with absolutely zero issues.

[image: screenshot showing XQuartz working]

Comment: Remember that it does open you up to X related security vulnerabilities. Just be on guard and keep it updated.

Comment: @BillSmith: Is XQuartz being actively maintained? Not much evidence of that on the GitHub site, but I only did a quick look.

Comment: Last updated October 2016. Abandonware?

Comment: @BillSmith: I duno' but the security must have been truly impressive if no updates have been required since 2016. I was just reflecting on your comment about "keep it upgraded".

Comment: @Seamus: Since 2016 a lot of public CVE's have been published for X11 (f. e. CVE-2017-13721). Most of them are minor, but still... I would really be surprised if macOS would be immune to all these CVE's. In my opinion, installing XQuartz is a security issue.

Comment: @BudBrot: Thanks for the feedback. Two comments: 1. What do you suggest one do; i.e. alternatives? 2. I only use XQuartz to connect to a RPi for Python IDLE; consequently, not sure I need be concerned. Back to you.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but one limitation is that it does not support Retina displays, meaning that the UI is quite pixelated on an Apple Retina display.

Answer (score 3):

To add a bit to @abc's answer:

1. I've had good luck with [XQuartz](https://www.xquartz.org/), but looking at the [XQuartz GitHub page](https://github.com/XQuartz), it would seem there's not a great deal of current activity (maintenance or new development) taking place.
2. I only use XQuartz over an SSH connection: `ssh -Y user@hostname`
3. You will need a `~/.Xauthority` file on your client machine (not the Mac). It should be generated automatically, but check for it.
4. I've got a few notes that might help you on [my GitHub page.](https://github.com/seamusdemora/PiFormulae/blob/master/XQuartzInstall.md)

Let us know if you have more questions.

Comment: XQuartz works fine when launching applications, but when launching a full X desktop using XDMCP it crashes. Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?